# Getting either an 500 internal server error or invalid value for stripe.confirmCardPayment

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, stripe-payments

I'm trying to make a payment component to my react app. This is my first time using stripe. I've tried to follow a tutorial, and I have done exactly the same thing as in the tutorial, but still getting an internal server error or `invalid value for stripe.confirmCardPayment` (see image below) when posting the request with axios. Hopefully someone can guide me onto the right track with this.

**CheckoutForm.js - HandleSubmit function**

```
handleSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { stripe, elements } = this.props;
    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      return;
    }

    const card = elements.getElement(CardElement);

    const {  } = await axios.post("/api/stripe/charge", {
      amount: 1000,
    })

    const paymentMethodReq = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
      type: 'card',
      card: card,
      billing_details: {
        name: 'Daniel Olsen',
        email: 'olsen.daniel04@gmail.com'
      },
      payment_method: {
        card: card
      }
    })

    console.log(paymentMethodReq)

    axios.get('/api/stripe/charge').then(function(response) {
      console.log(response)
      return response.json();
    }).then(function(responseJson) {
      var clientSecret = responseJson.client_secret;

      const confirm = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
        payment_method: paymentMethodReq.paymentMethod
      })
      
    });

    const result = await stripe.createToken(card);
    if (result.error) {
      console.log(result.error.message);
    } else {
      console.log(result.token);
    }
  };
```

**Stripe.js**

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('secret_key')

async function postCharge(req, res) {
  try {
    const { amount } = req.body

    const charge = await stripe.paymentIntent.create({
      amount: 2000,
      currency: 'nok',
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
    })

    if (!charge) throw new Error('charge unsuccessful')

    res.status(200).json({
      message: 'charge posted successfully',
      charge
    })
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      message: error.message
    })
  }
}

module.exports = postCharge
```

**server.js**

```
const app = express()
const router = express.Router()
const port = 3000

app.post('/stripe/charge', postCharge)
router.all('*', (_, res) =>
  res.json({ message: 'please make a POST request to /stripe/charge' })
)
app.use((_, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
  )
  next()
})
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use('/api', router)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../build')))

app.get('*', (_, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../build/index.html'))
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`server running on port ${port}`))
```

Error: [image]

Comment: the error is self explanatory, you're passing an object where a string is expected, or you've coerced an object to a string somewhere

Comment: what does `console.log(clientSecret)` and `console.log(typeof clientSecret)` output

Answer (score 0):

After you create the payment intent you're sending back the entire "charge" [sic] object in the json:

```
res.status(200).json({
  message: 'charge posted successfully',
  charge
})
```

While I'd suggest changing this to only send back the `client_secret`, the way you have it now the client needs to retrieve `responseJson.charge.client_secret`. You're missing that `charge` layer.

Comment: Still getting the error on the image above.

Comment: And if you add some debug logging, what is the object you're passing in?